# Navy blue dye bleeds?

Tags: dye, dyeing

I have recently been surprised at just how much red dye bleeds out of fabrics I have recently dyed whenever I wash them. I am using regular red Rit dye and natural fibers.

I was wondering if other colors will not do this as much, in particular Navy blue. I read somewhere that red dye bleeds the most, and that navy blue has a surprising amount of red in it.

I was wondering if anyone had had experience with navy blue dye. Does it bleed out red much or not?

Comment: Do you mean indigo-based dyes?